# Exctract minus sign from a variable

Tags: php

I've a peculiar situation, I need to split variable into two parts [sign] and [number]

So I can have following integers (this is not a sequence, I can have only 1 integer at a time):

```
-15,...,-1,0,1,...,15
```

When there is minus sign I need to split it into [-] part and [integer] part when there is no sign I need [+] and [integer]

How would I do this?

I was thinking to use explode with explode("-" but if there is no minus sign it will give errors... Any easy way to achieve what I want instead of writing multiple if functions?

Comment: Explode by commas then parse signs? Note: Better to write easy to understand code than writing a messy function that's 100% optimized (not saying it's bad to write short code, but if there's a simple solution without drawbacks use it)

Comment: `explode()` doesn't spit out errors when the delimiter is not found. You just get an array with 1 element (i.e. the string) in it.

Comment: @Raeki no commas to explode, I made a bad example. I can only have 1 single integer at a time and not sequence with commas.

Comment: So you are basically asking how to extract the sign part and the number itself from a random whole number?

Comment: Rewrite your question then.

Comment: [`$info = array();
if ($yourInteger < 0) {
 $info['sign'] = '-';
} else {
 $info['sign'] = '+';
}
$info['number'] = abs($yourInteger);`](http://codepad.viper-7.com/vnvVYU)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a single `integer`, you can do the following:

```
$singlevalue = -15;

$singlesplit = array('value' => abs($singlevalue));
if($singlevalue < 0)
    $singlesplit['sign'] = '-';
else
    $singlesplit['sign'] = '+';

print_r($singlesplit);
```

Which gives the output:

```
Array
(
    [value] => 15
    [sign] => -
)
```

**abs** here is important if you want to remove the sign of the value.

Also, if you receive your value as a string, simply use [intval](http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php)

```
$singlevalue = intval($stringValue);
```

Comment: I have only 1 integer at a time not sequence.

Comment: I clarified my answer for a single value

Answer (score 1):

```
$ints = '-1,2,-3,4,-5,6';
$signed_ints = explode(',', $ints);
foreach ($signed_ints as &$int) {
  if (intval($int) >= 0) {
    $int = '+' . $int;
  }
}
```

Comment: You misunderstood my question, my bad. I don't have sequence of numbers. For example today variable might be -1 tomorrow 15 day after 66 but never a sequence.

Comment: @SandroDzneladze just try this code with your dataset. David answered you exactly what you need.

Comment: It doesn't matter if it's a sequence, I just did that for the example. Try the code out, Sandro, unless your question is completely misstated and you're not doing what I think you're doing, this does the job.

Comment: @DavidFells How can I explode with comma, if $ints = '-1'; for example?

Comment: You should rewrite your question so that your source data is accurately represented.